# Math for sequential movement puzzles?

Tags: puzzle

It feels like there should be some area of math that can be used to make sequential movement puzzles like the 15-puzzle or Sokoban puzzles easier to solve. I guess for symmetrical examples like the 15-puzzle group theory can be helpful, but what about things like Sokoban where there isn't any obvious symmetry. Is it really just a matter of search algorithms and heuristics, or are there tools that can be used to simplify such problems?

Comment: Sokoban and many puzzles like it are NP complete, so they are (likely) inherently hard, meaning no such simplifying theories should exist.